# Permits for existing bathroom in 1950's house

Tags: bathroom, basement

Our house was built in 1956 by my Fiancé's grandfather. We recently ran into a problem with the town with the basement bathroom. His grandfather put the bathroom down there in the 1950's but it is not listed with the town. Now they are requiring permits and possibly tearing walls up to check plumbing, as well as fining us.

We are more then happy to comply with the CO's, just looking for advice on work. We did replace the yellow toilet and vanity and changed the outlet to GFCI.

Are there any grandfathered possibilities here? And if yes where could I look? We are located in New York, Suffolk county, Town of Babylon.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The electric is easy - very few requirements until the "dedicated circuit" (not sure when, but 1950s houses like mine didn't have it) and GFCI (much later and you already fixed). But plumbing gets complicated, and is much harder to check and/or retrofit than electrical. It sounds like that is the big concern - pipe types/sizes, venting, maybe other stuff.

Comment: For stuff to be grandfathered, it needs to be done to code when built.  Not being permitted in the first place, probably defeats it.

Comment: The grandfather clause usually applies to existing structures that remain in their original condition. You may run out of luck once you start making changes.

Comment: There do exist minimally-destructive inspection techniques. A USB or wireless borescope camera can be inserted through a small hole and give a view into walls or even be inserted into drain pipes. Walabot is a DIY tool that can give basic imaging of what's buried in a wall. Some plumbers have an inspection camera that gives even better images and also has a beacon so they can trace the path it travels underground (or under floor!). X-ray and ground-penetrating radar exist too but might be too costly.